# Is $\pi_2 (X_i)$ a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X_i)$-module for $i=1,2$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group, polyhedra, cw-complexes

Let ‎$‎‎X_1$ ‎‎be ‎the suspension of ‎$‎‎‎\mathbb{R}P^2‎$ and $X_2=\bigvee_{1\leq i\leq n} (\vee_{r_i} \mathbb{S}^i)$.

Is $\pi_2 (X_i)$ a projective (or a free) $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X_i)$-module for $i=1,2$?

I was wondering if someone could help me about my question. I don't have much information about $\pi_n (X)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and yes, respectively.

For $X_1$, the suspension is simply connected, so $\pi_2(X_1) = H_2(X_1) = H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) = \mathbb{Z}/2$ which is not a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module.

For the other one, $\pi_2(X_2) = H_2(\tilde{X}_2)$ where $\tilde{X}_2$ is the universal cover. Since $\pi_1(X_2)$ is a free group on $r_1$ letters (if I've understood your notation correctly),  $\tilde{X}_2$ is an infinite tree with a wedge of spheres (of dimension at least $2$) at each lift of the vertex of $X_2$.  Those spheres are permuted by the covering group action of $\pi_1(X_2)$, and so the homology of $\tilde{X}_2$ is free as a $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1(X_2)]$-module, with a fixed lift of each of the spheres (of dimension at least 2) as basis. In particular, $\pi_2(X_2)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1(X_2)]$-module on $r_2$ generators.

Because you can compute $\pi_2$ as $H_2$ of the universal cover, it's a lot easier than the higher homotopy groups.

Comment: Dear @DannyRuberman , I really appreciate if you could introduce me a reference concerning  $\pi_i (X)$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. I have problem with computing  $\pi_i (X)$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module for different $X$'s. For example, I don't know what $\pi_2 (S^1\times S^3)$ is as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module.

Comment: This is a basic topic, covered in most homotopy theory books. It's certainly in Whitehead's Elements of Homotopy Theory. A good choice might be Davis-Kirk's Lecture notes in algebraic topology. It's reasonable to do this for $\pi_2$, because $\pi_2(X)$ is $H_2$ of the universal cover of $X$, and the action is induced by covering transformations. Beyond $\pi_2$ it's no easier than any other sort of homotopy groups. Finally $\pi_2(S^1 \times S^3 = 0$ so there's not much to say.